# Show fullscreen when user clicks a button

Tags: android, onclick, android-fullscreen

I know the title is vague hope the picture will help you understand what i want.See how when the button is pressed it doesn't take the whole screen so the user has more space in his screen.It more useful than tabs,that is why i'm asking.Thank you for your time.

[image]

Comment: You mean a slide-out menu like everyone uses now?

Comment: I don't see what you mean? What button? A list item on the right? It looks like a list item on the right would be clicked and bring up a 'Products' list...

Comment: @Dave Newton exactly what your talking about.Is there any API or something?

Answer (score 4):

There is an open source library available [on github, called SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu), which does what you want to achieve.

You can check out the examples [here](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/tree/master/example) or you can download the Google Play demo app [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slidingmenu.example).